# Couldn't find openssl headers when building LibreOffice with Cygwin x64

Tags: openssl, cygwin, libreoffice

I faced an error when building LibreOffice with cygwin on Windows 10 64bit.

> buckets\ssl_buckets.c(49): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include
>   file: 'openssl /bio.h': No such file or directory

Spec:
cygwin64, LibreOffice 6.1, Visual Studio 2017, Windows 10
I installed openssl, openssl-dev on cygwin.
I checked /usr/include/openssl at cygwin, everything seems to be right.
What do I have to do?

Comment: I see a space in 'openssl /bio.h' . Is it real or a copy and past issue ?

Comment: When I setup cygwin, I selected "openssl-devel". But unfortunately, when compile libreoffice, it cannot find openssl headers.

Comment: Are you mixing windows and cygwin tool chains? Or are you using the mingw64 cross-compiler? When you are building within the cygwin environment, you must use only the cygwin tool chain. Be sure that the `make` program is the cygwin one and not a windows version. Execute `make -v` and look for "GNU Make 4.3" and "Built for X86_64-p-cygwin" as the first two lines of output.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've checked the version of make. GNU Make 4.2.1, Built for Windows32, I'd installed the make as following a guide to building libreoffice, https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/BuildingOnWindows

Comment: The instructions are a bit dated and they suggest a cumbersome hybrid mode of mixing Cygwin and Windows tools that could easily brake. Why you need to build LibreOffice ? The windows binaries are normally available.